# Convert HTML (JSX) from React into a string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How would I take HTML stored in a variable and convert it into a string?

Take this:

```
var html = <div>html</div>;
```

And Make it into this:

```
var html = "<div>html</div>"
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the flagged duplicate you can use [`ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring), or [`ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(element)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup) to render a react element as an HTML string (`renderToStaticMarkup()` doesn’t render the extra DOM attributes that React uses internally, such as `data-reactroot`).

Both methods can be used in both the server and browser environments.

```js
function App() {

const html = (<div>html</div>);

return (
  <div>
    {ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(html)}
  </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App  />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element's [`outerHTML` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML):

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('div');

var res = elem.outerHTML;

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

```html
<div>html</div>
```

Comment: In the context of React assigning JSX to a variable doesn't result in a DOM element being created, so this doesn't really answer the OP's question.